# Python - match/lookup

Tags: python, match, lookup

I have two lists, both containing a few thousand of lists within them. 
The first list is a stock trades list, each list within is an individual trade, with format

```
(datetime.date, str, str, int)
```

The second list is closing prices list, where each list within has format of

```
 (datetime.date, str, float)
```

I need to append all of the lists in the first (master) list with the relevant close price data from the second list, matching on datetime & the first tuple (security). Creating a match/lookup function based on both the variables has proved beyond me & any help setting this up would be much appreciated.

My code is as below:

```
for tradeline in tradeslist:
    for eodpriceline in eodpriceslist:
            if tradeline[0]==eodpriceline[0] and tradeline[1]==eodpriceline[1]
            print(eodpriceline[3])
```

but the error I get is:

```
    if tradeline[0]==eodpriceline[0] and tradeline[1]==eodpriceline[1]
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgetting the colon `:` at the end of your `if` statement:

```
if tradeline[0]==eodpriceline[0] and tradeline[1]==eodpriceline[1]
```

Should be:

```
if tradeline[0]==eodpriceline[0] and tradeline[1]==eodpriceline[1]:
```